# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -65

Tags: java, arrays, exception, pangram

i am trying to solve this question 
https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/pangrams
 and here's my code

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.math.*;
import java.util.regex.*;

public class Pangram {

public static String alltrim(String s)
{   String s1="";
    int i,j,k=0;
    for(i=0;i<s.length();i++)
    {
        char ch=s.charAt(i);
        if(ch!=' ')
        break;
    }
    for(j=s.length()-1;j>=0;j--)
    {
        char ch=s.charAt(j);
        if(ch!=' ')
        break;
    }
    for(k=i;k<j+1;k++) 
     s1 = s1 + s.charAt(k);

 return s1;
}
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
    String input = reader.nextLine();String s,s1;
    s = input.toLowerCase();
    s1 = alltrim(s);
    if( check(s1) )
        System.out.println("pangram");
    else
        System.out.println("not pangram");
}
public static boolean check(String input)
{
    int [] count = new int[26];
    for( int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++ )
    {
        char ch = input.charAt(i);
        count[ch-'a']++;
    }

    for( int cnt:count )
    {
        if( cnt ==0 )
            return false;
    }
    return true;
 }
}
```

i always get this error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -65
      at Pangram.check(Pangram.java:46)
      at Pangram.main(Pangram.java:35)
```

i am trying to find out where the problem is but i coudn't ... can anyone help me?

Comment: Well have you looked at Pangram.java line 46 and worked out why you're trying to access an invalid value? Have you tried debugging? Hint: your `alltrim` method doesn't actually remove all the space. You might want use `s1 = s.replace(" ", "");`...

Comment: @JonSkeet
thanks for that replace function
even after using replace function it is showing a similar problem 
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -43 at Pangram.check(Pangram.java:26) at Pangram.main(Pangram.java:15)

------> line 26 : count[ch-'a']++; -------> line 15 : if( check(s1) )
anything wrong with them?

Comment: It would also help to know which value you entered to encounter the out of bound exception.

Comment: Also, 4 of your 5 imports are not needed, you only use `java.util`.

Comment: input : 
6
aaabbb
ab
abc
mnop
xyyx
xaxbbbxx   @Jean-FrançoisSavard

Comment: int i,j,k=0;       Unnecessary. Do not need to declare them outside the loops as you are already declaring the required variables at the beginning of each for loop.

Comment: @coder101: Well again, have you tried debugging? It's *vital* that you learn how to diagnose problems yourself.

Comment: yes i do agree that it is important , i am actually coding in hackerrank and i do not have ide on this lappy , so i couldn't debug @JonSkeet

Comment: You can debug without IDE, answerer on StackOverflow always do this and they don't have magical powers.

Comment: @coder101: So you add logging statements, or you wait until you're in a place where you *can* debug. It's disrespectful to ask others to spend time just because you can't be bothered to wait until you've got access to a debugger, or add appropriate logging.

Comment: @coder101 Any feedback on this ?

Comment: i changed my code and reduced a lot of steps and it passed all the test cases , thanks to everyone for their responses and to your valuable time , i gotta better idea regarding out of bounds exception and also replace function came in handy

Answer (score 1):

## Here's one way

```
    public static void main(final String[] args) throws IOException {
         Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
         String line = reader.nextLine();
            // Verify input argument length.

            final char[] allCharacters = new char[] { 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j',
                    'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z' };

            
                    final TreeSet<Character> charactersPresent = new TreeSet<Character>();

                    // Parse the line into letters.
                    final char[] letters = line.toLowerCase().toCharArray();

                    // Keep a set of those that are present.
                    for (final char letter : letters) {
                            charactersPresent.add(letter);
                    }

                    // Print the letters present in the alphabet but not in the input.
                    final StringBuilder missingLettersBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                    for (final char character : allCharacters) {
                            if (!charactersPresent.contains(character)) {
                                    missingLettersBuilder.append(character);
                            }
                    }

                    if (missingLettersBuilder.length() == 0) {
                            System.out.println("This is  a PANGRAM");
                    } else {
                            System.out.println("Not a PANGRAM because it doesn't have "+missingLettersBuilder.toString());
                    }
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in

```
count[ch-'a']++;
```

where ch is `6`(as you entered) and you are subtracting `'6'-'1'` so its generating a value by subtracting the ASCII values and give

```
count[-43]++;
```

Answer (score 1):

The `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -65` happen because you subtract `a(97)` to a space character which is represented by `32` in the ASCII table (32-97=-65).

Which mean that the problem is in your `allTrim` method which does not replace all spaces as you probably expected.

If you want to replace all spaces of your string, you can use the `replaceAll` method of String.

Discard the `s1 = alltrim(s);` line and replace it by `s1 = s.replaceAll(" ", "");`.

Now entering the input you gave me in comments

> aaabbb ab abc mnop xyyx xaxbbbxx

Won't give any exception.

As for the other exception you had (out of bound -43), it is simply because you entered

> 6 aaabbb ab abc mnop xyyx xaxbbbxx

6 is represented by 54 in the ASCII table, 54-97 = 43. Looking at the requirement on the link you gave us, you should only compare alphabetical letter so I suppose this is a mistake.

Note that you can easily remove all number of a String, your replace line would become :

```
s1 = s.replaceAll(" ", "").replaceAll("\\d", "");
```

Now it would not give any error even when entering

> 6 aaabbb ab abc mnop xyyx xaxbbbxx